# Removing Access 2013 password

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2013

I have MS Office Access 2013 installed on my machine. I've set an application password a while ago but now I forgot...

**Since this is not a mdb or accdb specific password**, I couldn't find a way to solve this stupid problem.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You will have to brute force the password.